# Standard for identifying cities?

Tags: data, united-states, fips

I was doing a research project a little while ago and found out about [FIPS 6-4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_county_code) which is used to identify counties in the United States.  I also understand that this standard is a bit out of date.  Is there a similar standard for identifying cities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The U.S. Census Bureau used [FIPS 55-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Information_Processing_Standards) for some time, and much information is still encoded as such.  However it was discontinued, as it was volatile by design.  [It seems](https://ask.census.gov/faq.php?id=5000&faqId=6383) the replacement is called [GNIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_Names_Information_System).

[There's a FIPS-to-GNIS map available on Git](https://github.com/waldoj/FIPS-to-GNIS-Map/blob/master/united-states.csv).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider either of the following:

- [International Air Transport Association](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Air_Transport_Association)
- [United Nations Code for Trade and Transport Locations](http://www.unece.org/cefact/locode/service/location.html)